# Two lines chapters with Koma-Script

Tags: chapters, koma-script, scrbook

I'm using Koma-Script (`scrbook` class).
I want chapters with two lines:

## **This is line number one which contains the title of the chapter**

**This is line number two which contains the subtitle of the chapter**

Eeach one of them with diferent styles.

How can I do this?

Clarification:

The behaviour I want is like Christian suggested (see comments below):

```
\addchap{Chapter title \\ \somesize Chapter subtitle}
```

I don't know if there's an easy way to create a command (e.g. \chapterwsub) that do that in Koma-Script.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I don't know of subtitles of chapters. Do you mean a linebreak followed by a new line with smaller font size with additional text?

Comment: Something like this `\chapter{A long huge title\\ \normalsize followed with smaller font}`? But note, this should not appear in the table of contents. Use `\chapter[short title stuff]{Your very long title stuff \\ \normalsize subtitle}` for this

Comment: Yes, but with \addchap. I know how to do it manually. I would like a global solution, e.g., by modifying the \addchap command.

Comment: Do you want to add *just* the `\addchap` or numbered chapters as well? You can write *any* text/box directly after using `\chapter` (or define a macro for that). Redefining chapter is not recommended (by me).

Comment: Will there be a subtitle for *all* chapters? Or just for some?

Comment: As you can see by my questions, your question as it is right now is unclear and needs a lot of guessing. What happens when the subtitle is longer than one line? Do you want to be able to switch to another font mid-document. Do you want to toggle off subtitles later? And if yes, what to do with the material inside the subtitle? Discard it completely? Or let it be the first line of text? What happens to the space between chapter and text? Should the subtitle squeezed in there, or should it use additional space?

Comment: I've edited my question. I hope it is clear enough now.

Comment: No, not clearer. I guess i know what the output of the title should look like, but what input do you expect? Should it be it's own command? You mentioned headings, do you want this subtitle to appear in the running header? Please answer the other questions in the comments above as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This (trial of a) solution adds an additional optional argument to the `\chapter` command, which will hold the subtitle and will display it in the next line, using a somewhat smaller fontsize. If not present, there is no subtitle and everything behaves as usual.

In my point of view, it's no good idea, to get the subtitle into the page headers, as it will skew this and readability will suffer from this.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}


\usepackage{blindtext}%


\makeatletter
\let\LaTeXStandardChapter\chapter%

\NewDocumentCommand{\chaptersubtitlefont}{+m}{%
{\large \bfseries #1}%
}%

\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{s+o+m+o}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \LaTeXStandardChapter*{#3}%
  }{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#4}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
        \LaTeXStandardChapter{#3}%
      }{%
        \LaTeXStandardChapter[#2]{#3}%
      }%
    }{%
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}{ %     
        \LaTeXStandardChapter{#3\\ \chaptersubtitlefont{#4}}%
      }{%
        \LaTeXStandardChapter[#2]{#3\\ \chaptersubtitlefont{#4}}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%


\makeatother





\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\blindtext

\chapter{Another one}

\chapter*{Hello}

\chapter{My Chapter}[\textcolor{red}{With subtitle}]

\blindtext[10]


\chapter[Short chapter title]{My very long chapter title}[with short subtitle]

\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Something similar would be easily doable for `\addchap` as well.

Comment: @Johannes_B: You are free to do it :D

Comment: No i won't, a title and a subtitle are two different entities, related, but different and should be treated that way, different.

Answer (score 1):

A very basic version could be the following. But to make it bullet proof, more information are needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\newkomafont{chapsubtitle}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\newcommand{\chapsubvskip}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}
\newcommand{\chapsubtitle}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\usekomafont{disposition}\usekomafont{chapsubtitle}#1\par\endgroup%
\chapsubvskip\noindent\ignorespaces}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\addtokomafont{chapsubtitle}{\Large}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The duck that went crazy}
\blindtext
\chapter{The duck that went crazy}
\chapsubtitle{man, that was quit a riot}
\blindtext
\chapter{The duck that went crazy}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Gastón What exactly do you mean by heading? The part that appears on top of every page? Or the information that goes into the table of contents? Or something else?

Comment: @tohecz Sorry. Forget the headings.