# Subtitles for subsections in scrbook

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, section-titles

Is there a way to insert a subtitle right underneath a subsection heading in the scrbook class?

I found this [question/solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234704/2nd-column-in-toc-with-subtitles-for-subsection-and-subsubsection) - , basically exactly what I try to achieve, but I coulnd't make it work with the scrbook class..

Further, I found [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257481/subtitles-below-a-part), however I need the subtitle to be formatted slightly differently than the subsection heading, meaning not bold and sans-serif.

One reason why I need to have the subtitled treated as sort of a 'heading/title' is because I need the first line of the following subsection to appear with no indent.

Finally, I wish the subsection plus the subtitle not to be numbered (I'm currently using the starred version for subsections) and I do not wish the subtitle to appear in the TOC. I imagine something like this:

[image: Subsection with subtitle]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    11pt,
    ngerman,
    a4paper,
    open=any,
    headings=big,
    captions=tableheading,
    parskip=false,
    captions=nooneline,
    toc=listofnumbered,
    toc=bibliography,
    numbers=noenddot,
    bibliography=leveldown]{scrbook}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm, outer=2.5cm,tmargin=3cm, bmargin=4cm]{geometry}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Part I}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection*{Subsection}
Subtitle\\
First line of subsection with no indent.

\end{document}
```

Comment: To clarify: You "do not wish the subtitle to appear in the TOC", but the (unnumbered) subsection should appear in the TOC, right? See my answer, where I worked under this assumption.

Comment: No, I'm sorry for not being clear on that. I don't want the subsection nor the subtitle to appear in the TOC.

Comment: Great, then only the first part of my answer applies; for the rest, you are good with `\subsection*`.

Comment: Many thanks @marquinho for your efforts, plus the added explanation of your code. It's perfect. It works just exactly how I imagined it. You made my day, a big thank you!

Comment: One detail I just realised: the `\newcommand{\subsecsubvskip}{\vspace{1ex}}` adjusts the space between the subtitle and the subsection text and not the space btw title and subtitle. However, I could adjust the latter with `\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-10pt,afterskip=1pt]{subsection}`

Comment: You're welcome! And that's right, `\subsecsubvskip` is actually the space *after* the subtitle. You found a solution for the spacing *before*. Btw, I'd suggest adding a (positive or negative...) `vspace` to the subtitle command instead: `\newcommand{\subsecsubtitle}[1]{\vspace{-1ex}\begingroup` etc. This way, it impacts only those sections where a subtitle is used – and not all sections, as in your method with `\RedeclareSectionCommand`.

Comment: And finally, consider the expert suggestion by a [true KOMA-Script expert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/635874/) which is actually cleaner and more organic than mine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a new section command `\subsecsubtitle`

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterskip=.5ex
]{subsection}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  level=\subsectionnumdepth,
  afterskip=1.5ex plus .2ex,
  beforeskip=-.5ex,
  indent=0pt,
  font=\mdseries\small,
  tocstyle=gobble% no TOC entry
]{subsecsubtitle}
```

Then you can use

```latex
\subsection*{Subsection}
\subsecsubtitle*{Subtitle}
```

to get an unnumbered subsection followed by the unnumbered subtitle. This also avoids a page break between the subtitle and the following text.

Note that `beforeskip` of the subtitle is ignored if `\subsecsubtitle` is next to another section command.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
    %11pt,% default
    ngerman,
    %a4paper,% default
    open=any,
    %headings=big,% default
    captions=tableheading,
    %parskip=false,% default
    captions=nooneline,
    toc=listofnumbered,
    toc=bibliography,
    numbers=noenddot,
    bibliography=leveldown]{scrbook}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm, outer=2.5cm,tmargin=3cm, bmargin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterskip=.5ex
]{subsection}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  level=\subsectionnumdepth,
  afterskip=1.5ex plus .2ex,
  beforeskip=-1pt,
  indent=0pt,
  font=\mdseries\small,
  tocstyle=gobble
]{subsecsubtitle}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Part I}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection*{Subsection}
\subsecsubtitle*{Subtitle}
First line of subsection with no indent.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the organic, comprehensive solution and (among other things) for taking care of avoiding page breaks.

Comment: Many thanks @esdd! I adopted your code one to one. It works and it looks just wonderful! Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: I included a setting to adjust the vertical spacing between title and subtitle, which was missing, as indicated by OP.

---

### Subtitle

The best approach, I think, would be to follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213651) and define a custom command `\subsecsubtitle` for exactly this purpose.

The command includes the desired font specifications and the direction `\noindent`. Note that this is only a *mock* sectioning command: it has all the visual trappings of a title, but it *does not send anything to your TOC* or to the running headers.

```
\newkomafont{subsecsubtitle}{\small\mdseries\sffamily} 
% subtitle font: smaller than \subsection; not bold; sans-serif
\newcommand{\subsecsubvskip}{\vspace{1ex}}
% adjust the vertical space between subtitle and text

\newcommand{\subsecsubtitle}[1]{%
\vspace{-1ex}% % adjust the vertical space between title and subtitle
\begingroup\usekomafont{disposition}\usekomafont{subsecsubtitle}#1\par\endgroup%
\subsecsubvskip\noindent\ignorespaces}
```

You can then employ this command right after `\subsection`:

```
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsecsubtitle{Subtitle}
First line of subsection with no indent.
```

### Numbering and starred commands

You would like the `\subsection` to remain unnumbered, which is why you are using the *starred* version. But I also gather from your question that, while *the subtitle* shouldn't go to the TOC, *the subsection* ought to do so. However, your starred command `\subsection*` doesn't send anything to the TOC.

*If* I understand you correctly, then this is **one way** to do it:

```
\subsection*{Subsection title} % unnumbered section
\addxcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Subsection title} % manually create TOC entry
```

This sends the specified title to TOC. However, you have to do it *manually* for every subsection.
**A better way** is to generalize the operation, by creating a new command that does just that (argument `#1` is the desired title):

```
\newcommand*{\subsectnonum}[1]{%
\subsection*{#1}
\addxcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}}
...
\begin{document}
...
\subsectnonum{Subsection}
```

(**Another option** would be to use the `nonumber` switch when invoking the section: `\subsection[nonumber=true]{Subsection}`. This requires to activate the package option `headings=optiontoheadandtoc` in the preamble. You can read more about this powerful option and about "the advanced functionality of the optional argument of the sectioning commands" in the [documentation](https://mirror.informatik.hs-fulda.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide.pdf#page=104).)

### Example

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\newkomafont{subsecsubtitle}{\small\mdseries\sffamily}
\newcommand{\subsecsubvskip}{\vspace{1ex}}

\newcommand{\subsecsubtitle}[1]{%
\vspace{-1ex}%
\begingroup\usekomafont{disposition}\usekomafont{subsecsubtitle}#1\par\endgroup%
\subsecsubvskip\noindent\ignorespaces}

\newcommand*{\subsectnonum}[1]{%
\subsection*{#1}
\addxcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
\subsection*{Normal subsection (no TOC!)} % normal subsection, no number, no TOC
\subsecsubtitle{Subtitle}
First line of subsection with no indent.

\section{Section 1}
\subsectnonum{Custom subsection}    % custom subsection w/o number
\subsecsubtitle{Subtitle}
First line of subsection with no indent.

\end{document}
```

[image: TOC and section titles]